# Adding four numbers of 1 bit each and then cascading them

Tags: adder, binary, summing, carry-look-ahead, multiplication

When I add four bits (NOT FOUR BIT ADDER, only four bits), the result can go to a maximum of 100 (4 in decimal, if all are ones). Now, here 0 (LSB) is the sum and 10 is carry. If I want to transfer this carry to further 4 bits (such as in the case of multiplication when we transfer carry of one partial sum to other), shall I add these two bits 10 together (which would be incorrect in my opinion)? What would be the correct procedure?

> Blockquote

Comment: See also: [Bit counter using basic logic gates](/q/244661), [Wallace tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct procedure is to handle each bit according to its *weight*.
The carry outputs of a "bit adder with 4 inputs" with binary output have a weight of 4× and 2× the weight common to the inputs and the "least significant" output.

If it had another same weight input *and two weight-2 outputs*, it would be a *4-2 compressor*.
The distinction between *carry* input/output and others isn't entirely arbitrary:
in the usual block diagram with two full adders/3-2 compressors, while the signals travel two blocks between regular inputs&outputs,
there is just one block between regular inputs & carry output, same between carry input & regular outputs. (And no path from carry in to carry out.)

Comment: Alright! So after your answer I figured out that all i needed was to propagate the second carry generated in nth sum to (n+2)th sum, in this way it would be treated according to its weight. Thanks for the help!